# Java - Find Element in Array using Condition and Lambda

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, java-stream

In short, I have this code, and I'd like to get an specific element of the array using a condition and lambda. The code would be something like this:

```
Preset[] presets = presetDALC.getList();
Preset preset = Arrays.stream(presets).select(x -> x.getName().equals("MyString"));
```

But obviously this does not work. In C# would be something similar but in Java, how do I do this?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can do it like this,

```
Optional<Preset> optional = Arrays.stream(presets)
                                   .filter(x -> "MyString".equals(x.getName()))
                                   .findFirst();

if(optional.isPresent()) {//Check whether optional has element you are looking for
    Preset p = optional.get();//get it from optional
}
```

You can read more about `Optional` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: Using `isPresent()` and `.get()` is discouraged as it kills the purpose of using optional.

Comment: Not directly. The main reason to use Optional is to force a check (to trigger a bug as early as possibly). Using get() is okay if you can prove that it holds, which he does. I agree though that in general its better to use the alternatives. But there are many situations in which you can not directly name a default or want to throw an exception, instead you may want to have the error handling in the `if-else` of `isPresent()` and then use `get()`.

Comment: Your answer was helpful for me. I wanted the same exact thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

Like this:

```
Optional<Preset> preset = Arrays
        .stream(presets)
        .filter(x -> x.getName().equals("MyString"))
        .findFirst();
```

This will return an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) which might or might not contain a value. If you want to get rid of the `Optional` altogether:

```
Preset preset = Arrays
        .stream(presets)
        .filter(x -> x.getName().equals("MyString"))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null);
```

The `filter()` operation is an intermediate operation which returns a lazy stream, so there's no need to worry about the entire array being filtered even after a match is encountered.

Answer (score 12):

Do you want first matching, or all matching?

```
String[] presets = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "CA"};

// Find all matching
List<String> resultList = Arrays.stream(presets)
                                .filter(x -> x.startsWith("C"))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(resultList);

// Find first matching
String firstResult = Arrays.stream(presets)
                           .filter(x -> x.startsWith("C"))
                           .findFirst()
                           .orElse(null);
System.out.println(firstResult);
```

*Output*

```
[C, CA]
C
```

Answer (score 0):

## One-liner since Java 8:

```
Preset found = Stream.of(presets)
    .filter(p -> p.getName().equals("MyString"))
    .findFirst().orElseThrow();
```

Avoid declaring Optional<>, that returned from `findFirst` as a variable or a parameter. It is designed for return types / "one-liner" styles.

- see [javadoc **API Note**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)
- see [26 Reasons Why Using Optional Correctly](https://dzone.com/articles/using-optional-correctly-is-not-optional)

Comment: Is there a one-liner that doesn't throw an exception in the case of a missing element? E.g. something you could toss into a conditional so you can then add the missing element if needed.

Comment: @Fopedush, absolutely:  `...findFirst().orElse(MY_EMPTY_OBJ);`. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-