# Getting only first element of ArrayList that matches condition

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I've been trying to find possible answers, but found none.

I've got an `ArrayList` full of custom objects. One of their fields is a `boolean`.

**I want to put this object first, keeping the rest of elements**

For instance, if I've got this list and `obj5` is the one with this boolean set to true:

```
obj3, obj2, obj5, obj7, obj9
```

I'd like to get this:

```
obj5, obj3, obj2, obj7, obj9
```

**EDIT: CAN'T USE LAMBDAS, JAVA 6**

**EDIT 2: PLEASE NOTE THAT THE REST OF THE LIST MUST KEEP THE OLD ORDER**

**EDIT 3: In short words, I need this program to output [B, A, C, D, E]:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Trip {

@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}

private String name;
private boolean freeCancellation;


public Trip(String name, boolean freeCancellation) {
    this.name = name;
    this.freeCancellation = freeCancellation;
}

static Comparator<Trip> myOrder = new Comparator<Trip>() {
    public int compare(Trip a, Trip b) {
        if (a.freeCancellation == b.freeCancellation) return 0;
        return a.freeCancellation ? -1 : 1;
    }
};

public static void main(String [] args){
    Trip t1 = new Trip("A", false);
    Trip t2 = new Trip("B", true);
    Trip t3 = new Trip("C", false);
    Trip t4 = new Trip("D", true);
    Trip t5 = new Trip("E", false);


    List<Trip> tripList = new ArrayList<>();
    tripList.add(t1);
    tripList.add(t2);
    tripList.add(t3);
    tripList.add(t4);
    tripList.add(t5);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tripList.toArray()));
    Collections.sort(tripList, myOrder);
    //result should be [B, A, C, D, E]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tripList.toArray()));
}

}
```

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262059/java-find-element-in-array-using-condition-and-lambda)?

Comment: So, it's basically a collection *sort* with custom comparator, right?

Comment: you could try to implement compareTo of Comparable.

Comment: @YogevLevy yes, but that uses Java 8 and I need Java 6

Answer (score 6):

Write a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

```
Comparator<MyType> myOrder = new Comparator<MyType>() {
    public int compare(MyType a, MyType b) {
         return (b.booleanField() ? 1 : 0) - (a.booleanField() ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Sort using this comparator.

```
Collections.sort(myList, myOrder);
```

See [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

#### Edit

So it seems that what you're actually asking for is to move **just one** matching element to the front of your list. That ought to be pretty easy.

Find the index of the element you want to move:

```
int foundIndex = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < tripList.size(); ++i) {
    if (tripList.get(i).freeCancellation) {
        foundIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you find such an element, and it is not already at the start, move it to the start:

```
if (foundIndex > 0) {
    tripList.add(0, tripList.remove(foundIndex));
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not mantaining order in the rest of the list

Comment: @stackman From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)): "This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort."

Comment: I've updated the question so you can see what I am actually speaking about, thanks for your answer btw

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to achieve this:

```
class Element {
    public boolean shouldBeFirst();
}

List<Element> elements;
elements.sort(Comparator.comparing(Element::shouldBeFirst));
```

This works because the natural ordering of booleans is true first.

If you can't use Java 8 then the equivalent would be something like:

```
Collections.sort(elements, new Comparator() {
    int compareTo(Element el1, Element el2) {
        return (el1.shouldBeFirst() ? 1 : 0) - (el2.shouldBeFirst() ? 1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry sprinter, forgot to say I can't use Java 8

Comment: well... isn't there something like retrolambda? ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<Object> objList = findObj(name);Collections.sort(objList, new Comparator<Object>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object a1, Object a2) {
        return (a1.getBooleanField()== a2.getBooleanField())?0:(a1.getBooleanField()?1:-1);
    }});
```

This might help you to resolve this. You modify the results by changing the compare logic

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
        list.add(new A(true));
        list.add(new A(false));
        list.add(new A(true));
        list.add(new A(false));
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}

class A implements Comparable<A> {
    private boolean b;

    public A(boolean b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public boolean isB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(boolean b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(A a) {
        return a.isB() ? 1 : -1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A [b=" + b + "]";
    }



}
```

Maybe this is what you are looking for.
This is solution if you want to give natural ordering to object, then implement Comparable and use Collections.sort - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List).
If you have various members inside class, then maybe go with Comparator implementation, that way you can achieve many ways of sorting your objects based on different members.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood what are you asking ,you need to create a new class called "Comparators".
in this class you need to define your methods and they need to be `static final ...`
then you can use it by calling to `Collections.sort(-your array-, Comparator method name);`

Comment: `you need to create a new class called "Comparators"` why ? `they need to be static final ...` why ?

Comment: there is no need for `static final` i think.

Comment: They need to be static final because Collections.sort need to "know" the params from the begging