# Java - How to get item index from an array with its value?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

If I have a array list say a string array, then how can I get index of an element with its value?

Code exammple:

```
    private static final String[] TEST = new String[]{
      "abc","bcd","def"
}
```

require its index with something like:

```
       int i = TEST.getPosition("abc");/TEST.indexof(...);//not available
```

Also I tried with creating ArrayAdapter.

Is there anything like this? Or maybe I need to assign it with that adapter or something?

Or,

How can I get such index of an element?

Comment: You want the index of an element, or an element from a index?

Comment: Even if there would be no such method  still you could write own one (which you should learn on algorithms basics)

Comment: index with its value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the index of an element in an array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522108/how-to-find-the-index-of-an-element-in-an-array-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Simplest idea**:

> Convert array to list and you can get position of an element.

```
List<String> abcd  = Arrays.asList(yourArray);
int i = abcd.indexOf("abcd");
```

**Other solution**, you can iterator array:

```
int position = 0;
for (String obj : yourArray) {
    if (obj.equals("abcd") {
       return position;
    }
    position += 1;
} 

//OR
for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.length; i++) {
    if (obj.equals("abcd") {
       return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I‘d rather use a normal for-loop than a foreach-loop like you did for this example, you do not have to worry about any external variable and it’s more compact.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32262092/5784924)  and use the Java 8 Lambda `filter` function.

```
Optional<String> optional = Arrays.stream(presents)
                               .filter(x -> "MyString".equals(x.getName()))
                               .findFirst();

if(optional.isPresent()) {//Check whether optional has element you are looking for
    String s = optional.get();//get it from optional
}
```

the filter function take a lambda callback and will returns a list with only the values that match the condition in the lambda. In our case, we also want only the first one. That's why are add the `findFirst()` which will returns only the first value.
The function will returns an `Optional`, we can check if it contains a value using `options.isPresent()`.
 The `optional.get()` will returns the value.
 
Replace the `"MyString"` by your value and it should work.

If you wish to find an index, you can use the `indexOf()` function after changing your static array to an list : `Arrays.asList(array)`;

Answer (score 1):

There can be two methods which you can opt for -

1) First, as it is an array, you can simply run a for loop and compare using equals() and find the position.

2) Secondly, convert it into an List<> and run indexOf() and find the position.

NOTE: When you convert an array to List, it become a backed version List, it is fixed and size can't be alter --> but it is perfectly fine in your case as your array is final.

```
List<String> str = Arrays.asList(TEST);
int pos = str.indexOf("abc");
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the simplest method is `Arrays.asList(TEST).indexOf("abc")`. But here's an alternative using streams:

```
int index = IntStream.range(0, TEST.length)
        .filter(i -> TEST[i].equals("abc"))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(-1);
```