# Get element from list using lambda/callback - JS equivalent of Array.prototype.find()

Tags: javascript, java, list, arraylist

I want to get an element (NOT the index) from a Java list using a callback.

In JavaScript, there is the `Array.prototype.find` method that does exactly that.
For example:

```js
let match = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].find((num) => num === 3);
console.log(match); // 3
```

Is there a Java equivalent?

Comment: Are you trying to find the index or trying to find the element 3? If you're looking for 3 why would you return 3? Wouldn't you just want to know if it exists or not?

Comment: Hi. i want the element, NOT the index.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - Find Element in Array using Condition and Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262059/java-find-element-in-array-using-condition-and-lambda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to determine if a number exists in an array or collection you can simply use IntStream#filter.

```java
int value = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).filter(v -> v == 3).findAny().orElse(-1);
```

Comment: The op was asking about finding a number in an array...

Comment: No, OP explicitly said a List. If he is using a List he can most certainly use a Stream.

Comment: Lol well regardless your example also does not include a list

Comment: @RobOhRob Because unless you had a predefined list you would almost never create a list so that you can filter through it when you can just use a Stream. Why would you use Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).stream() when you can just use Stream.of(1, 2, 3) or IntStream.of(1, 2, 3) in this case. You would literally be creating a List, then a Stream.

Comment: Lmao so you're saying that IntStream implements the list interface?

Comment: Guys, please. No need for hostility; thanks for trying to help. I'm new to Java, i'm coming from JavaScript background. In JS, there is the Array.prototype.find method AND Array.prototype.findIndex method (i find JS to be much more flexible as a language). Not sure if there was a Java Equivalent.

Comment: @Jason constructive criticism can be helpful Jason. I was simply stating that this answer did not show how to filter a list... I personally don't consider an IntStream to be a list, because it doesn't implement the list interface and I'm not aware of any other lists in java

Answer (score 6):

You can do so using Java Stream API.

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = List.of(10, 20, 30, 40, 50).stream().filter(n -> (n == 30)).findAny().orElse(-1);
        System.out.println(x);
        int y = List.of(10, 20, 30, 40, 50).stream().filter(n -> (n == 3)).findAny().orElse(-1);
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
30
-1
```

Use [findAny() or findFirst()](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-findfirst-vs-findany) depending on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, yes! this is what i was looking for. Is there the possibility of null pointer exception here?

Comment: You are most welcome. I've added one more example in which the value is not present. I hope, it helps.

Comment: @ryanwaite28 No because findAny() returns an Optional of Integer. ifPresent is only called if Optional is not empty, meaning a value was found.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same in Java using lamda function:

```
 Optional<Integer> result = Arrays.stream (array).filter(num -> (num==3)).findAny();
 result.ifPresent(num -> System.out.println(name));
```

Comment: Hi, i found something that helps - https://www.baeldung.com/find-list-element-java

Comment: basically this: Object item = someList
          .stream()
          .filter(i -> i.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
          .findAny()
          .orElse(null);

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried

```
list.stream().filter(n -> n == 3 ).findFirst().ifPresent(n -> doSomething(n))
```

?

Comment: Object item = someList
          .stream()
          .filter(i -> i.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
          .findAny()
          .orElse(null);

Answer (score 0):

I Kinda found what i was looking for on this site - https://www.baeldung.com/find-list-element-java

Basically this:

```java
Object item = someList
  .stream()
  .filter(i -> i.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
  .findAny()
  .orElse(null); 

if (item != null) {
  // ...
}
```