# How do I look for an element in a array string java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Question originally [posted in Spanish, on es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/407996/c%c3%93mo-busco-un-elemento-en-una-arreglo-de-string-java), by [Fernando Méndez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/195127/fernando-m%c3%a9ndez):

> Ask for a name to search for, read that name from the keyboard and go
> through the array to verify if it exists, if it is found, show a
> message indicating that if the name x is found, otherwise, show a
> legend, the name x is not found.
>
> This is my code but when executing and comparing the elements it only
> takes the last element of the array and that is the one that compares
> the others are omitted.
>
> ```
> package arrreglo_practicas;
>
> import java.util.Arrays;
> import java.util.Scanner;
> import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
>
> public class Arrreglo_Practicas {
>
>     
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
>        
>        
>         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
>         
>         String busqueda = "";
>         int  elements = 0 ;
>         String aux = null ;
>         //tomando el valor e insertarlo en el arreglo 
>         
>         elements = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "digite la cantidad  de elementos  del areglo "));
>         //arreglo de "n" elementos 
>         
>         String [] arreglo = new String [elements];
>         
>         //recorriendo el arreglo para que tome los valores 
>    
>         for (int x = 0;  x <arreglo.length; x++){
>             System.out.print("|ingresa  los nombres| ");
>             aux = input.nextLine();
>             arreglo[x] = aux; 
>         }
>         //búsqueda inicial 
>        busqueda = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null," busca un nombre:");
>        
> //parte que se ejecuta mal
>
>         if (busqueda.equals(aux)){
>             for (int a = 0; a < aux.length(); a++)
>            System.out.println("si se encuentra el nombre:"); 
>             
>         }else {
>             
>             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"dicho nombre no existe: ");
>         }
>          
>     }
>     
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the equality inside the for loop one by one with each input array value.

```
//parte que se ejecuta mal
     boolean isMatch = false;
    
        for (int a = 0; a < arreglo.length; a++) {
          if (busqueda.equalsIgnoreCase(arreglo[a])) {
            isMatch = true;
            System.out.println("si se encuentra el nombre:");
          }
        }
    
        if (!isMatch)
    
        {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "dicho nombre no existe: ");
        }
```

**Java 8 (as suggested by paulsm4 in comments):**

In Java8 with Stream you can do as below:

```
//parte que se ejecuta mal
    final Optional<String> optionalMatched = Arrays.stream(arreglo).filter(a -> a.equalsIgnoreCase(busqueda))
        .findFirst();

    if (optionalMatched.isPresent()) {
      System.out.println("si se encuentra el nombre:");
    } else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "dicho nombre no existe: ");
    }
```

But additionally you would need to update the `busqueda` declaration as below to make it final.

```
String busqueda;
```

Comment: In java8 or higher, you can also use streams: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32262092/421195